# DNS Format Error

Tags: dns, udp

I am getting a Format Error with DNS. Any idea on what is it?

```
Client /root #dig @2029:192:168:119::170 ns udp.net +bufsize=50000 +tries=10 ns +noqr
;; Warning, extra type option

; <<>> DiG 9.3.1 <<>> @2029:192:168:119::170 ns udp.net +bufsize=50000 +tries=10 ns +noqr
; (1 server found)
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: FORMERR, id: 55070
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 50000
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;udp.net.           IN  NS

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 2029:192:168:119::170#53(2029:192:168:119::170)
;; WHEN: Thu Nov  8 14:49:08 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 36
```

Not able to find any useful material on Google.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing when trying to query my load balancer

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to nail down an exact cause, but there are a couple of themes that have come up from the research I've done:

- It seems to be frequently attributed to misconfigured load balancers.
- It seems to occur only when an EDNS record is sent.

For instance, some samples:

```
$ dig AAAA gtm03.wallst.com @209.234.224.40

; <<>> DiG 9.9.2 <<>> AAAA gtm03.wallst.com @209.234.224.40
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: FORMERR, id: 29393
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;gtm03.wallst.com.              IN      AAAA

;; Query time: 80 msec
;; SERVER: 209.234.224.40#53(209.234.224.40)
;; WHEN: Fri Mar 15 02:51:24 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 45

$ dig +noedns AAAA gtm03.wallst.com @209.234.224.40

; <<>> DiG 9.9.2 <<>> +noedns AAAA gtm03.wallst.com @209.234.224.40
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 23716
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;gtm03.wallst.com.              IN      AAAA

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
wallst.com.             300     IN      SOA     dns01.wallst.com. dnsadmin.wallst.com. 2911145386 7200 3600 86313600 300

;; Query time: 82 msec
;; SERVER: 209.234.224.40#53(209.234.224.40)
;; WHEN: Fri Mar 15 02:51:38 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 85
```

I get that same output on different hosts, on two different continents.

As nearly as I can tell, this is the fault of the server you're querying, not your own resolver.